# How to Avoid API data response from cache in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, internet-explorer-11, browser-cache

I'm making an API Call using JavaScript but while making a call for second time, I'm getting that data from cache.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />  
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />  
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

I've included above meta Tags in Head Section of HTML.

and also while making an API call, I've intecepted the request with below headers.

```
   { "Cache-Control" : "no-cache" , Pragma: "no-cache", Expires: "-1" }
```

but still I'm getting that api data from cache for second time.
This issue is only for the IE.

apart from below mentioned tags I've also tried with

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />    
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
```

But it couldn't help much.

Can anyone please suggest the solution.

Thanks,

Comment: I've gone through this link for IE and try to set it up but it is not working. 
 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234067/how-to-prevent-caching-in-internet-explorer

Comment: For testing purpose, Try to open developer tools and go to network tab and enable the 'Always refresh from server' option. Here you can see in image. https://i.postimg.cc/q7rD6djb/75.png Check whether it makes any difference or not. I will try to find any other solution using code and try to inform you.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, Thanks for help. "Always refresh from server" is working as expected, please let me know if you get something on your end, as working debugger mode is not good experience :)

Comment: @ Harshal, I try to find the code to always refresh the data from server. I find that most of the things you had already tried. There are no any other code available that can do the same. I find Cache.delete() method but it is also not supported in IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete

Answer (score 1):

Disabling webpage caching in Internet Explorer 11

The StorageGRID Webscale Installer web page might appear to function incorrectly if you use webpage caching in Internet Explorer 11. You must disable caching if you want to use this browser to access the Installer web page.

Steps
From the top right corner of Internet Explorer 11, click the Gear icon gear icon.
From the menu, select Internet options.
On the General tab, locate the Browsing history section, and click Settings.
On the Temporary Internet Files tab, confirm that Every time I visit the webpage is selected.
Website Data Settings > Temporary Internet Files > Every time I visit the webpage selected
On the Caches and databases tab, confirm that Allow website caches and databases is not selected.
Website Data Settings > Caches and databases > Allow website caches unselected
Click OK.